# First posts review audit should not fail you for commenting

Tags: feature-request, comments, review, review-audits

I got a first posts audit (https://serverfault.com/review/first-posts/121442, on [Monday morning mistake: sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root /](https://serverfault.com/questions/587102/monday-morning-mistake-sudo-rm-rf-no-preserve-root)), and not knowing it was an audit, I wanted to leave a comment indicating a case where the answer would not have helped.

For some reason this is an audit fail, because apparently good answers are immune to comment.  Can it not be one?

I realize that this means someone could bypass the review by clicking "add comment" all the time, but that is still more effort than roboreviewing, and it's more important that the audit not harass well-intending reviewers.